# Trouble while deserializing multidimentional json object in c# using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am deserializing an json object with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
object is like this:

```
"journalItemAccounts":"{\"item1\":\"2222\"}"
```

My deserialize code is:

```
jsonResult.accountsData.journalItemAccounts != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonResult.accountsData.journalItemAccounts) : null;
```

**jsonResult.accountsData.journalItemAccounts** contains **"journalItemAccounts":"{\"item1\":\"2222\"}"**

This is deserializing perfectly. But what if i need to deserialize the object like this:

```
"journalItemAccounts":"{\"item1\":{\"incomeAccount\":\"5030\",\"expenseAccount\":\"\",\"assetAccount\":\"\"}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start `DeserializeObject` with `Dictionary<string, object>` and check whether the value is `Object` or `Value`. Here is the example method to convert the `Json` to pick the value or object

```
public class item1
{
    public string incomeAccount { get; set; }
    public string expenseAccount { get; set; }
    public string assetAccount { get; set; }
}

public static void ParseJson(string json)
{
    var keyValuePairs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
    foreach (var keyvaluepair in keyValuePairs)
    {
        var obj = keyvaluepair.Value.ToString();
        decimal itemvalue;
        if (decimal.TryParse(obj, out itemvalue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(itemvalue);
        }
        else
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<item1>(obj);
            Console.WriteLine($"{ result.incomeAccount } - {result.expenseAccount} - {result.assetAccount}");
        }
    }            
}
```

Call this method to get the desired result

```
ParseJson("{\"item1\":\"2222\"}");

ParseJson("{\"item1\":{\"incomeAccount\":\"5030\",\"expenseAccount\":\"5031\",\"assetAccount\":\"0532\"}}");
```

Output

```
2222

5030 - 5031 - 0532
```

Comment: thankyou Krishna for your answer its very useful. can you add one more solution on the same answer that if "journalItemAccounts" is not fixed either it could be "{\"item1\":\"2222\"}" or it could be "{\"item1\":{\"incomeAccount\":\"5030\",\"expenseAccount\":\"5031\",\"assetAccount\":\"0532\"}}"
then how we are going to retreive its values

Answer (score 1):

Create a type and pass that like this.

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(jsonResult.accountsData.journalItemAccounts);

public class Model
{
    public AnotherModel item1 { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherModel
{
    public string incomeAccount { get; set; }
    public string expenseAccount { get; set; }
    public string assetAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanyou for the solution, i have try all the given solutions, all are helpful. @krishna Muppalla has given more brief including your solution

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because you are using string as value. You use an Object type or a class instead.

```
jsonResult.accountsData.journalItemAccounts != null ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Object>>(jsonResult.accountsData.journalItemAccounts) : null;
```

Comment: thankyou prisar for your solution. Exactly i need to define dictionary with object too to fetch the valus of object type